# what will be the reason behind the output of java code?

Tags: java, operators, increment, decrement

Consider the following simple java code

```
public static void main(string args[])
{
  int x=10;
  int y;

  y=x++;
  y=y--;

  System.out.println(y);
}
```

here output is 10. but actually y variable decrements.
but according to me output should be 9.
what is the reason?

Comment: `y=y--` is the same as `y=y`. It has no effect on the value of `y` **at the end** of the assignment.

Comment: `y = x++;` the same `y = x; x += 1;` , `y = y--; (y = y , y -=1)`

Answer (score 3):

**The postfix-increment operator works as follows:**

- Increment the operand
- Return the previous value of the operand

**The postfix-decrement operator works as follows:**

- Decrement the operand
- Return the previous value of the operand

**Therefore, the following piece of code works as follows:**

```
x = 10;  // x == 10
y = x++; // x == 11, y == 10
y = y--; // y ==  9, y == 10
```

---

As you can see, `y = y--` is equivalent to `y = y`.

It has no effect on the value of `y` at the end of the operation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand about prefix and postfix operators.

`y=x++` means assign x to y and then increment x by 1;

`y=++x` means increment x and then assign the incremented value to y.

If you understand this difference then its obvious what the code does.

Comment: I don't know how this answer is different from above answer so it got 2 votes up! 
+1

Comment: I don't think what you stated is equivalent to barak's answer.  Your answer implies that the decrement occurs after the assignment. According to your statement, `y=y--` is equivalent to `y=y; y=y-1;` which is not the same as what the other answers are saying...

Comment: explaining something to a beginner in sample code is often confusing as against explaining the same thing in plain English.

Answer (score 0):

The post-decrement operator returns the old value of the variable. So when you write

```
y = y--;
```

it decrements `y`, then assigns the old value back to `y`. It's as if you wrote:

```
old_y = y; // Save old value
y = y - 1; // perform y-- decrement
y = old_y; // Assign the saved value
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's whats happening

```
int x=10;
```

> declare a vaiable x and assign 10 to it.

```
int y;
```

> declare a variable y

```
y=x++;
```

`increment x therefore x=11 and return its old value therefore y=10`

```
y=y--;
```

> decrement y therefore y=9 at current point, and return its old value which is 10 and is caught by y therefore y=10 now.

```
System.out.println(y);
```

**Output**

```
10
```

Answer (score 0):

x = 10;  // x == 10

y = x++; //Here First Y is asigned with value 10 and increments x by 1

y = y--;//Here First Y is asigned with value 10 and decrements y by 1

Because If we use Postincrement or postdecrement First it asigns value to Variable then it performs increment or decrement .